# Hide the status while playing movie using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone

I already hide the status bar in my application using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];`. But when I play movie then automatically it display the status bar on the top.

Does anyone knows that how to hide the status bar while playing movie.

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` notification and make sure the status bar is hidden as soon as playback starts.

Your handler would look something like that :

```
- (void)playbackStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *mpv = (MPMoviePlayerController *)notification.object;
    if (mpv.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653236/hide-statusbar-from-mpmovieplayercontroller

Comment: I tried several different approaches and this was the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    [AppShare.viewController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
    //[self.view addSubview: playercontroller.view];
    [self.view addSubview:playercontroller.view];
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0);
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [playercontroller.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
    playercontroller = nil;
```