# iPhone MPMoviePlayerController : Hiding the status bar

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide the status while playing movie using MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910170/hide-the-status-while-playing-movie-using-mpmovieplayercontroller)

It seems that if you play a movie full screen the status bar is turned back on.  You can hide it on movie load but as soon as you click the controls to come up it reappears.  There seems to be no movie controls appear events.

Update:
This is only an issue if you tab the screen for the movie controls to come up.  Its something to do with the movie control.

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise you could:

Use this when you want it to show:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO]];
```

Use this when you want to hide it:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO]];
```